# Getting value from previously generated resultset

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a Stored Procedure in which I am running a query twice to get the desired output like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetSeries`(IN id INT)
BEGIN
   select pid from                      //<----This Query is executed twice
       (select pid from poststatus 
           where uid = id and pid > 10 
           order by pid desc limit 50
       ) T

UNION

select pid from postshare where uid = id and pid 
between 10 and               
       (select pid from                //<----Running The previous query again
       (select pid from poststatus          
           where uid = id and pid > 10 
           order by pid desc limit 50
       ) T limit 1);             
END
```

I want the query execute once and later on get the value from that query. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the output of the first query into a temporary table.
Read the first `pid` in the list into local variable and use the same in second query.

`UNION` the temp table records with the second query for desired results.

**Example**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetSeries`( IN id INT )
BEGIN
  declare _pid int;

  create temporary table pid_list_50 as 
    select pid from poststatus 
     where uid = id and pid > 10 
     order by pid desc 
     limit 50;

  select pid into _pid from pid_list_50 limit 1;

  select * from pid_list_50
  union
  select pid from postshare 
   where uid = id and pid between 10 and _pid;

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE pid_list_50;
END
```

Comment: Ravinder thanks for your answer and I already had done so after asking this question but yet appreciate your support thanks.